# React Native Slider - onValueChange invoked too many times

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a Slider on my app but whenever I start dragging the thumb, it keeps flickering. It's because I'm using the state directly and storing it whenever it changes. I'd like for the value to update whenever I move it not only when I stopped. Tried using a common variable out of the state with forceUpdate() but it happens the same thing, multiple updates lag a lot.

This is the code I'm using to create the slider

```
export default class Profile extends Component {

constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.state = { age: 18 }
  } 

  render() {    

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Slider
         style={{ width: 300 }}
         step={1}
         minimumValue={18}
         maximumValue={71}
         value={this.state.age}
         onValueChange={val => this.setState({ age: val })}
        />
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          {this.state.age}
        </Text>            
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

In order to stop the flickering I'm using the `onSlidingComplete` parameter to update the state, but that only triggers when I release the finger from the component. Not the desired effect.

Should I add a debounce or something on this setState?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either debounce or throttle the `setState` call. With Lodash:

```
....
onValueChange={_.debounce(this.setAge, 33)} // 30 updates per second
onValueChange={_.debounce(this.setAge, 16)} // 60 updates per second (too much!)
....

setAge(age) {
    // Don't forget to bind this function to your component on the Constructor function!
    this.setState({ age })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I gotta check what's that "Lodash", never used it. I will give it a read :) and come back in a few

Comment: Okay, used 33 as debounce timing and works perfect now, thanks Rodolfo :)

Answer (score 3):

You can stop the lag by commenting out the `value` prop of the `<Slider />`. That prop is just for the initial slider value, but it is creating the lag...

I am assuming you want to display the slider value in a `<Text>` component somewhere. You can do that by creating 2 pieces of state for the actual, logical piece of state that you have. One of those 2 would display the data in a text component (and you would update it `onValueChange`) while the other one would update the actual slider value and could be used as the 'value' prop (and you would update it `onSlidingComplete`).

I wrote a detailed answer (with code) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65198567/4345461).